# How to execute unionBugs and convertXmlToText (Findbugs) from the command line on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, findbugs

I'd like to run some of the data mining techniques discussed on this page: 
http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/datamining.html#unionBugs via the command line on Windows.  I've searched all over for examples, but nothing has shown me the syntax required.  I've run Findbugs plenty of times using `java -jar %FINDBUGS_HOME%\lib\findbugs.jar`, but can't get the data mining commands to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert XML to text:

```
java -cp findbugs.jar edu.umd.cs.findbugs.PrintingBugReporter -txt analysisResult.xml >output.txt
```

Union bugs:

```
java -cp findbugs.jar edu.umd.cs.findbugs.workflow.UnionResults -output out.xml input1.xml input2.xml ...
```

Comment: Thanks you! Is there any documentation I could check for this?  Mainly just to find the correct package name to use (like "edu.umd.cs.findbugs.workflow.UnionResults").

Comment: Unfortunately this is probably not documented. I know these classes, because I participate in FindBugs development, but seems that the only documented things are those shell scripts which eventually perform the same command.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for the help either way! I guess I can just take a look at the shell scripts of other commands if I need to figure out how to run them.